# How do you use Threads with MVC?

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller

I have a group project in Java. We're to simulate customers collecting parcels from a post office. 
- Customers come at random intervals
- Parcels arrive after long intervals
- Clerk waits for customers; when there is one - he hands them the parcels.

I've made a customer and a parcel thread which adds customers and parcels as needed. I've also made a clerk thread that sleeps until customers arrive.

The problem is how do Threads fit in with MVC?

I've made separate Runnable classes for each thread. Do I pass the view to their constructors?

Comment: Why use threads here? It doesn't seem appropriate. It's much simpler to use Queues and various Actors/Messages

Comment: It's a requirement for the project.

Comment: Are you asking how to integrate threads with a frontend process?  Or how to display the results?  Or maybe how to use threads to simulate web traffic?

Comment: This looks like you want to make stress test to your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've made separate Runnable classes for each thread. Do I pass the view to their constructors?

No, a "background" task as such doesn't feed the view directly.  The component that is common to all layers of the application is the model.  Threads that are doing work in the background should update the appropriate model as they complete their work.  The view Observes the model to update itself as needed.

Comment: Sounds more like a MV*M - not than I'm opposed to such.

Comment: IMO "MVC" has long since degraded into little more than a marketing term with no consistent definition across various frameworks and platforms.  It's used to sell technology stacks to product managers who remember the horror of maintaining VB6 and want to be told it'll be different this time because "This one has MVC"  /rantdone :)

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense :) Thanks. So my controller sees the model has changed and updated the view while the thread continues to go its stuff in the background.

Comment: That is completely opposite to what Affe suggested .. Why did you accept the answer if you decided to ignore it?